# How to "Leave Room" in flask_socketio?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, flask-socketio

I am creating a chatting app, and I am trying to let users use a button to leave the room.
I tried the socketio function `leave_room`, but the user still remains in the room, although the chat saying the user has left. My code:
`application.py`

```py
import os
import requests

from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)
channels = {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', channels = channels)

@app.route("/chat")
def chat():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    channel_id = request.args.get("channel_id")
    if username and channel_id:
        channels[channel_id] +=1
        return render_template("index.html", username=username, channel_id=channel_id)
    print("Wait")
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


@socketio.on('join_room')
def join_room_event(data):
    app.logger.info("{} has joined channel {}. ".format(data['username'], data['channel']))
    join_room(data['channel'])
    socketio.emit('joined_room', data)

@socketio.on('leave_room')
def leave_room_event(data):
    app.logger.info("{} has left channel {}.".format(data['username'], data['channel']))
    leave_room(data['channel'])
    socketio.emit('left_room', data)

@socketio.on('self_leave_room')
def self_leave_room(data):
    channel_id = data['channel']
    channels[channel_id] -= 1


@socketio.on("send")
def vote(data):
    emit("announce message", data, broadcast=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`home.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if message != () %}
        <h4 class="text-danger">{{ message }}</h4>
        {% endif %}
        <form action="{{ url_for('chat') }}">
            <div>
                <label>Enter your name:</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="username">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Enter Channel ID:</label>
                <select name="channel_id">
                    {% for channel in channels %}
                    <option value="{{ channel }}">{{ channel }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Enter Room</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

                // Connect to websocket
                var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

                socket.on('connect', () => {
                    socket.emit('join_room', {
                        'username': "{{ username }}",
                        'channel': '{{ channel_id }}'
                    })
                });

                // The button should emit the value of the textbox
                document.getElementById('send').onclick = e => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let message_input = document.getElementById('textbox');
                    const message = message_input.value.trim();
                    if(message.length){
                        socket.emit('send', {
                            'message': message,
                            'username': "{{ username }}",
                            'channel': "{{ channel_id }}"
                        });
                    }
                    message_input.value = '';
                    message_input.focus();

                };

                document.getElementById('leave').onclick = () =>{
                    const data = {
                        'username': '{{ username }}',
                        'channel': '{{ channel_id }}'
                    };
                    socket.emit('leave_room', data);
                    socket.emit('self_leave_room', data)

                };

                socket.on('left_room', data =>{
                    if (data.channel === "{{ channel_id }}"){
                        const inner = document.createElement('div');
                        inner.innerHTML = `<b>${data.username}</b> has left the room.`;
                        inner.style.backgroundColor = "#e1f3fb";
                        inner.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
                        inner.style.fontSize = "12px";
                        inner.style.borderColor = "#d5cec7";
                        inner.className = "rounded";
                        inner.style.display= "inline-block";
                        inner.style.border= '2px solid #d5cec7';
                        const div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.appendChild(inner);
                        div.style.width = "100%";
                        document.getElementById('message').appendChild(div);
                    }
                });


                socket.on('joined_room', data => {
                    if (data.channel === "{{ channel_id }}"){
                        const inner  = document.createElement('div');
                        if (data.username !== "{{ username }}"){
                            console.log('not me.');
                            inner.innerHTML = `<b>${data.username}</b> has joined the channel!`;
                        } else {
                            console.log('me.');
                            inner.innerHTML = `<b>You</b> joined the channel.`;
                        }
                        inner.style.backgroundColor = "#e1f3fb";
                        inner.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
                        inner.style.fontSize = "12px";
                        inner.style.borderColor = "#d5cec7";
                        inner.className = "rounded";
                        inner.style.display= "inline-block";
                        inner.style.border= '2px solid #d5cec7';
                        const div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.appendChild(inner);
                        div.style.width = "100%";
                        document.getElementById('message').appendChild(div);
                    }
                });

                socket.on('announce message', data => {
                    console.log(data.channel);
                    console.log("{{ channel_id }}");
                    if (data.channel === "{{ channel_id }}") {
                        const inner = document.createElement('div');
                        const div = document.createElement('div');
                        inner.innerHTML = `${data.username}: ${data.message}`;
                        inner.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
                        inner.style.fontSize = "12px";
                        inner.style.borderColor = "#d5cec7";
                        inner.className = "rounded";
                        inner.style.display = "inline-block";
                        inner.style.border = '2px solid #d5cec7';
                        if (data.username === "{{username}}") {
                            inner.style.backgroundColor = "#dcf8c7";
                            div.style.textAlign = "right";
                        } else {
                            inner.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
                            div.style.textAlign = "left";
                        }
                        div.appendChild(inner);
                        div.style.width = "100%";
                        document.getElementById('message').appendChild(div);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
           body{
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
           }
           div{
                padding: 2px 12px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Messages on Channel {{ channel_id }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Channel {{ channel_id }}</h1>
        <button id="leave" onclick="{{ url_for('home') }}">Leave Channel</button>
        <label for="textbox"></label><input id="textbox" placeholder="Message..." type="text">
        <button id="send">Send</button>
        <hr>
        <div id="message">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
socketio.emit('left_room', data,room = data['channel'])
```

At the very least you need to specify the argument room.
Otherwise messages for channel x, will be broadcasted to every other room
You will need to do this in both js aswell as python.

> but the user still remains in the room, although the chat saying the
> user has left

Is there any way to verify this?

Comment: I have an `'if (data.channel === '{{channel_id}})` statement in the javascript portion.

Comment: also, when I receive the "left_room" socketio, I find that the `<div>` is indeed created to all users in that room ONLY. But, the leaving user still does not get redirected to the mainpage, as well as not receiving an error for not inputting any redirect page. (I don't know where to put it)

Comment: This answer is correct. You are broadcasting your messages to everyone. Add `room` argument in your emits so that they are restricted to the people that are in the room.